# Convert String value into a list of custom objects

Tags: java, json, parsing, collections, java-11

I have a String  `[{max=0.0, min=0.0, co=3.0},{max=0.0, min=0.0, co=3.0}]`
  I want to convert it to `List<CustomObject>` where Custom Object is a Java class as

```
CustomObject{
   Integer max;
   Integer min;
   Integer co;
  //getter setter
}
```

Is there any optimal way to cast or convert?

Comment: It looks like a json string but it really isn't. First you will need to convert this to json string, you can use regex for it and then use Jackson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a short way to do it using only the Java standard library. But if you use an external library like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), it's quite easy:

```
String str = "[{max=0.0, min=0.0, co=3.0},{max=0.0, min=0.0, co=3.0}]";

// Parse str to list of maps
List<Map<String, Double>> list = new Gson().fromJson(str, List.class);

// Convert list of maps to list of CustomObject
List<CustomObject> objects = list.stream().map(map -> {
    CustomObject obj = new CustomObject();
    obj.min = map.get("min").intValue();
    obj.max = map.get("max").intValue();
    obj.co = map.get("co").intValue();
    return obj;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```